# PHP on WordPress - If the link contains ID "124" run this .js file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, redirect

I use WordPress on my local server.
To perform a redirect after a user has completed the contact form with the Plugin Contact Form 7 I want him to be redirected to a specific page.

I tried a plugin that I found but it doesn't work and the site crashes.

I would like that:

- user goes to page with ID 2. Once the contact form has been completed, clicking send will call the file home-it.js.
- User goes to page with ID 96. Once the contact form has been filled in, clicking on send will call the file home-de.js
  etc.

I tried this PHP code but it didn't work:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


if (strpos($url,'2') !== false) { 
    ?> <script type="text/javascript" src="home-it.js"></script> <?php
} elseif (strpos($url,'124') !== false) {
    ?> <script> type="text/javascript" src"home-fr.js"></script> <?php
} elseif (strpos($url,'96') !== false) {
    ?> <script type="text/javascript" src="home-de.js"></script> <?php
} elseif (strpos($url,'82') !== false) {
    ?> <script type="text/javascript" src="home-en.js"></script> <?php
}
```

If I put the JS file on the page it works perfectly.
But the hoh system recognizes the page ID.

Can you help me?
Thanks so much,
Pascal

Answer (score 0):

Contact Form 7 provides several types of custom DOM events. You can utilize the events within your JavaScript code to run a function in a specific situation.

In your case, you may want to try the `wpcf7submit` custom DOM event:

```
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );
 
wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
  alert( "Fire!" );
}, false );
```

For more information about CF7 events:
https://contactform7.com/dom-events/

Also, about your code - it's not a good practice to search for the ID in the URL:
Consider a very probable situation when you have pages with ids 96 and 196 your code will run for both because you are searching for 96

An alternative could be using the native WordPress function `get_the_ID()` to retrieve the ID of the current item (See here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/)

Maybe try:

```
<?php
$post_id = get_the_ID();

if ($post_id == 2) { 
    ?> <script type="text/javascript" src="home-it.js"></script> <?php
} elseif { ... }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.
Who has set me wordpress and apache has something wrong and now no longer recognizes the IDs.
Meaning: if I use your formula or tell wordpress to use permalinks it doesn't work.

For this I need to be able to parse the link and redirect accordingly